# How to create a selectlist which is also a input text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a select-list like one shows in google mail search. The special thing of that selectlist is when we click over the select list it becomes a input text box and when we click over the right-side down arrow of that selectlist it shows a drop-down form which contains search options to search a specific mail.

I just want to know how to create a selectlist which also behaves like a input text box if we click over the box area ?

Can anyone please give me an idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

I hope you are looking something like this

http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select-2.1.html

Check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery-ui autocomplete plugin.

[Autocomplete - Combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

you can have the detailed documentation here..

[A jQuery UI Combobox: Under the hood](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/a-jquery-ui-combobox-under-the-hood)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight. this is using JQuery